# Stop-WebAppPool does not stop pool, at the same time I can stop it in IIS panel

Tags: powershell, iis, web-deployment

I'm using poweshell remoting to restart application pool during deployment.

Before delpoyment site is switched to offline mode using `app_offline.html`.

Also I deploy temporarary `web.config` to prevent early restarts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Environment" value="development" />
        <add key="Deployment" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime waitChangeNotification="300" maxWaitChangeNotification="300" />
        <!-- <customErrors defaultRedirect="app_offline.htm" mode="On"/> -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then webdeploy installs new version.

The powershell remote commands are executed `Stop-WebAppPool -Name $poolName`/`Start-WebAppPool -Name $poolName`.

Then I deploy full `web.config` and remove `app_offline.html`.

The problem is that `Stop-WebAppPool` does not stop pool, it stays forever in `Stopping` state (according to powershell `Get-WebAppPoolState`). At the same time I can go to IIS panel and do stop pool manually without any problems. There is single pool, single machine, so everything is correct. Somehow webdeploy and `app_offline.html` breaks powershell commands, I tested restart script separately it works as expected.

---

Relevant thread: https://help.octopus.com/t/issues-stopping-app-pools-during-deploy-when-autostart-being-used/20837

Comment: What do you mean Stop-WebAppPool does not stop pool and it stays forever in Stopping state? This command is used to stop pool to prevent it running.

Comment: @BruceZhang, I execute `Stop-WebAppPool` then I check pool state using `Get-WebAppPoolState` and it reports state is `Stopping` instead of `Stopped`.

Comment: What IIS version are you running?  What `startMode` do you have configured?

Comment: @tukan, I've tried both startModes with the same result, IIS 10

Comment: I see.  Did you try the procmon from sysinternals to see what is actually happening?

Comment: @tukan, I can see pool process is running and has the same ProcessId, so it was not restarted. Is there something specific that I should look for?

Comment: I don't have IIS 10 to test on.  I would search for the `Stop-WebAppPool` trying to stop the pool - the process should disappear and be stopped.  `Restart-WebAppPool` I would expect the pool process to be stopped and restarted.  To me it seems you are missing some permissions to restart the service.  Are you sure your user has the correct permissions?

Comment: @tukan, yes, I can run the script (without any msdeploy commands or website manipulations) and it does restart pool, so I assume that all permissions are in place.

Comment: I see.  Could you run this command on the server after you try to stop the service and it is in the stopping state?  `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_service | Where-Object {$_.state -eq 'stop pending'}`  What do you get?